# Refetch data when screen is focused

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Struggling with what I thought was a simple concept..

When a screen is focused, I want it to reload, unless I specify otherwise.

My screen is accessed from a bottom tab navigator, as well as other places in the app.

Using `useFocusEffect`, I can add this code which does trigger a reload:

```
    const focusRefresh = useCallback(() => {
      loadData();
    }, [user?.userId, .. other deps here..]);
  useFocusEffect(focusRefresh);
```

So I'm halfway there. However, some screens (such as a modal with more information), when they close and `navigate` back, I don't in this situation want another refresh. I'm struggling to get this. I can add some params when I go back from this modal:

```
navigator.navigate('Screen1',{dontRefresh:true})
```

But the issue here is that once I set this param, it seems to always be present. So after doing this, if I then navigate around via the bottom tabs, then I observe that the `dontRefresh` param is thereafter always present.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check "dontRefresh" param in the constructor so it would trigger only once when you navigate to the screen firstTime not always like from modal ec

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using functional react, the dontRefresh is passed as a navigational param with react native.